# How to use CoCreateInstance() to get a com object?

Tags: c++, com, mingw

I had registered a COM component.And I want to call it.

```
CLSID clsid;
RIID iid;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("se.mysoft"),&clsid);
LPVOID *pRet;
HRESULT hr1 = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, iid, pRet);
```

I can get the clsid successful, but where can I get the iid ?

I used OLE VIEWER find interface:

```
 [
 odl,
 uuid(F3F54BC2-D6D1-4A85-B943-16287ECEA64C),
 helpstring("Isesoft Interface"),
 dual,
 oleautomation
 ]
 interface Isesoft : IDispatch {
```

Then I changed my code:

```
CLSID clsid;
RIID iid;
IDispatch* pDispatch;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("se.mysoft"),&clsid);
HRESULT hr1 = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,  IID_IDispatch,(void **)&pDispatch);
```

But hr1 returned failed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the Interface ID of a COM class so that it can be passed to CoCreateInstance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313432/how-to-retrieve-the-interface-id-of-a-com-class-so-that-it-can-be-passed-to-cocr)

Comment: What is the exact value of hr1?

Answer (score 7):

Your COM class implements some interfaces and each interface has its `IID` identifier. So you need to get it from your COM component implementation. It's your code and you are expected to provide the identifier which exactly specifies what interface you are requesting.

Some COM classes implement well known interface, esp. `IDispatch`, the identifier for which is `IID_IDispatch`, or `__uuidof(IDispatch)`.

UPD. Since you found that the interface of interest is `Isesoft`, your code will be:

```
CLSID clsid;
RIID iid;
IDispatch* pDispatch;
HRESULT nResult1 = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("se.mysoft"), &clsid);
HRESULT nResult2 = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
  IID_Isesoft, (void **) &pDispatch);
```

To get `Isesoft` and `IID_Isesoft`, `__uuidof(Isesoft)` available to C++ code, you will need to import the definitions, which is typically either of then two:

- additional vendor SDK includes e.g. `#include "isesoft\sdk.h"`
- or [`#import "libid:..."`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) with type library identifier (namespace and other attributes apply)

When you have `HRESULT` codes indicating failures, make sure to post the values.

Comment: The com class isn't created by me and I can't see the code and IID identifier.Then I use IID_IDispatch ,but the program can't work(It can be compiled but failed in running).

Comment: If the COM library/component is not yours, you need additional information from the vendor, or you might possibly looks up the identifiers via type library (see [COM/OLE Viewer tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx)).

Comment: I can call it in VB: set se = createobject("se.mysoft"). I don't know how to call it in c++

Comment: _"Some COM classes implement well known interface"_ Well then, might be worth pointing out that ***all*** COM classes implement _at least_ `IUnknown` :)

Comment: I found the implement, but I still failed.

Comment: I found a header file of the COM component. I am trying to include and compile it. But here are so many errors. I am repairing it.

Comment: My compiler is MINGW, I can't use '__uuidof'.

Comment: `IID_Isesoft` is another option - depends on the header you use, it might/should be defined there this way.

Comment: IID_Isesoft was not declared. The header I use only include one class Idmsoft.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that your `CLSID` is correct, since `hr` has a value of 0. From the extract of your idl.file, I conclude that the interface‘s ID is {F3F54BC2-D6D1-4A85-B943-16287ECEA64C} and its name `Isesoft`. Your present code provides a pointer to `IDispatch` and `hr1` should be 0 if `hr` is 0. To get a raw COM pointer to this interface you must pass the CLSID and the IID as well as the address of a pointer to `Isesoft`.

Now change your code:

```
CLSID clsid;
RIID iid;
IseSoft* pIceSoft; 
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("se.mysoft"),&clsid);
HRESULT hr2 = IIDFromString(OLESTR("{F3F54BC2-D6D1-4A85-B943-16287ECEA64C}"), &iid);
HRESULT hr3 = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, iid, (void **)&pIseSoft);
```

A final remark: Since your `hr1` returns a fail which it shouldn't, I presume that something is wrong with the CLSID. You can find the correct  CLSID in the idl file from where you got the IID oft he interface.

Nevertheless, with your code all you would get is a useless `IDispatch` pointer, because that is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should know the interface you want on your object, let call it `IMyInterface`.

```
IMyInterface* pItf = NULL;
hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMyInterface, (void**)&pItf);
```

Comment: Where can i find the interface?  I don't have the COM component's source code. I can call it in VB:                                        set se = createobject("se.mysoft")                                       I don't know how to call it in c++.

Comment: @CodeCat have you tried importing the .dll ? That generates header files that you can include to access the COM object. Just write #import "yourdll.dll" in your cpp file (and make sure you got a path to it)

Comment: when I imported dll file and compiled it , the compiler show many error.